# Compute matrix multiplication only for given coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, sparse-matrix

In PyTorch, I would like to compute

```
E * A.mm(B)
```

where E can be a very sparse matrix consisting of 0's and 1's. In other words, I want to compute A.mm(B) and then leave only the certain coordinates. Is there a way to compute such a sparse matrix efficiently? I have full control over matrix representations.

Also, in most cases, E consists only of 1's, so I would like this case also to be handled efficiently.

Comment: Can you update the question to ideally include a [mcve] of your problem? It is not quite clear what the desired output dimension of the sparse matrix multiplication should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an element-wise multiplication for that, as `E` is essentially a boolean matrix, that is used as a mask to select the values, where `E` is 1, and discard the values where `E` is 0.

```py
C = A.mm(B)

# Ensure that E is a boolean matrix to only keep values where E is True,
# otherwise the 0s and 1s would be treated as indices to select the values.
C = C[E.to(torch.bool)]
```

If you want to avoid the entire matrix multiplication and only compute the values you would be masking afterwards, you need to manually select the values for `A` and `B` that produce the desired values in `C`.

The matrix multiplication *C = AB*, where *A* is an *m x n* matrix and *B*  an *n x p* matrix, produces an *m x p* matrix *C*, whose values are obtained by multiplying the *i-th* row of *A* with the *j-th* column of *B* element-wise and taking the sum of these *n* products. Formally:

[image: Matrix Multiplication Formula]

Given *E*, an *m x p* matrix, that determines which elements of *C* are required, the index pairs of the required elements are given as follows:

[image: Indices]

```py
# Indices of required elements (i.e. indices of non-zero elements of E)
# Separate the tensor of (i, j) pairs, into a pair of tensors,
# containing the indices i and j respectively.
indices_i, indices_j = E.nonzero().unbind(dim=1)

# Select all needed rows of A and the needed columns of B
A = A[indices_i]
B = B[:, indices_j]

# Calculate the values
# B is transposed to change the column vectors to row vectors
# such that the two can be multiplied element-wise.
C = torch.sum(A * B.transpose(0, 1), dim=1)
```

---

Is it more efficient to selectively calculate the values you want compared to performing the entire matrix multiplication and then only keep the values you want?

The answer is a resounding *No*. The matrix multiplication is highly optimised, much more optimised than doing the steps manually with operations that themselves are well optimised. Especially, when *E* contains mostly 1s, then you're basically re-implementing the matrix multiplication, which is guaranteed to be less efficient. Even for the case where *E* contains mostly 0s, the matrix multiplication is just faster.

To support my claims, I've timed them. For convenience I did it in IPython, which has the built-in [`%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) command.

```py
In [1]: import torch
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: def masked(A, B, E):
   ...:     C = A.mm(B)
   ...:     return C[E]
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: def selective(A, B, E):
   ...:     indices_i, indices_j = E.nonzero().unbind(dim=1)
   ...:     return torch.sum(A[indices_i] * B[:, indices_j].transpose(0, 1), dim=1)
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: A = torch.rand(1200, 1000)
   ...: B = torch.rand(1000, 1100)
   ...: # Only 10% of the elements are 1
   ...: E_mostly_zeros = torch.rand(1200, 1100) < 0.1
   ...: # 90% of the elements are 1
   ...: E_mostly_ones = torch.rand(1200, 1100) < 0.9

In [2]: # All close instead of equal to account for floating point errors
   ...: torch.allclose(masked(A, B, E_mostly_ones), selective(A, B, E_mostly_ones))
Out[2]: True

In [3]: # All close instead of equal to account for floating point errors
   ...: torch.allclose(masked(A, B, E_mostly_zeros), selective(A, B, E_mostly_zeros))
Out[3]: True

In [4]: %timeit masked(A, B, E_mostly_ones)
8.16 ms ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit selective(A, B, E_mostly_ones)
2.09 s ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [6]: %timeit masked(A, B, E_mostly_zeros)
5.73 ms ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

] In [7]: %timeit selective(A, B, E_mostly_zeros)
266 ms ± 3.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The matrix multiplication is staggeringly fast, being over *256x* faster when *E* contains 90% ones (8.16ms vs 2090ms), and over *46x* faster when *E* contains only 10% ones (5.73ms vs 266ms).

Comment: It doesn't solve the original problem: I multiply matrices A and B and leave only few coordinates in the end. I want to only compute the coordinates I have to compute.

Comment: *I multiply matrices A and B and leave only few coordinates in the end*, that is precisely what I've provided. But I've updated the answer to also include a version where only the computations are performed for the values you want.